# TextBlock inside DataGridTemplateColumn does not refresh if source changed

Tags: wpf, xaml

There is a **TextBlock** inside **DataGridTemplateColumn**, that which initially bound to a ViewModel property (Guest.FirstNames), displays value correctly. However, when that property in ViewModel is changed, the change does not reflect in the View. Here are the relevant code

**RoomSlot**

```
public class RoomSlot : EntityBase {
    [Required]
    public Guest Guest { get; set; }
}
```

**Guest**

```
public class Guest : EntityBase {

    private string _firstNames;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "FirstNames is Required")]
    public string FirstNames {
        get { return _firstNames; }
        set { _firstNames = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FirstNames); }
    }
    public List<RoomSlot> RoomSlots { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
<!-- DataGrid.DataContext = ObservableCollection<RoomSlot> -->
<!-- DataGridTemplateColumn.DataContext = RoomSlot -->

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Guest" Width="auto" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Guest.FirstNames, Mode=OneWay}"
                           FontWeight="Normal"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MakeReservationViewModel : Conductor<object> {

    private ObservableCollection<RoomSlot> _roomSlots;
    public ObservableCollection<RoomSlot> RoomSlots {
        get { return _roomSlots; }
        set { _roomSlots = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RoomSlots); }
    }

    //changedRecord contains updated Guest
    public void Handle(RecordChanged<Guest> changedRecord) {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (RoomSlot slot in RoomSlots) {
            if (slot == currentlyEditingSlot) {
                slot.Guest = changedRecord.Record;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RoomSlots[i].Guest.FirstNames);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RoomSlots);
            }
            i++;
        }
   }
}
```

As you can see, I am changing the **Guest.FirstNames**. The **Guest** is a property of **RoomSlot**. The **Guest.FirstNames** when updated in ViewModel does not reflect the change in View. Why does TextBlock not refresh inspite of raising NotifyOfPropertyChanged (caliburn micro's implementation of INotifyPropertyChagned)

**EDIT**

**This is In ViewModel**

```
//This is where I Initially receive new RoomSlots from another class
public void Handle(List<RoomSlot> roomSlots) {
    RoomSlots = new ObservableCollection<RoomSlot>(roomSlots);
    //If I Apply Guest Names here as given below, they appear correctly in View
    foreach (RoomSlot slot in RoomSlots) {
        slot.Guest.FirstNames = "Sarah Anderson";
    }
}
```

This above code initializes ViewModel ObservableCollection property for first time. At this point Guests Names are not known, but if I (for testing) initialize Guest.FirstNames as done above, I correctly get the bindings to work and "Sarah Anderson" appears in the DataGridTemplateColumn.

**EDIT 2**
Finally it works if I change the definition of **RoomSlot.Guest**

**from this**

```
public class RoomSlot : EntityBase {
    [Required]
    public Guest Guest { get; set; }
}
```

**To This**

```
public class RoomSlot : EntityBase {

    private Guest _guest; 
    [Required]
    public Guest Guest {
        get { return _guest; }
        set { _guest = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Guest); }
    }

}
```

Although I am not sure why explicitly raising `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RoomSlots[i].Guest)` doesn't work, but the above change does

Comment: Your Guest class does not have a FirstNames property in your code?

Comment: @PhilWright , It does have. I just didn't show that. I will edit my question and show FirstNames property.

Comment: Don't you need to do the NotifyOfPropertyChanged of the whole "guest" object? I think the whole object is being changed here, instead of only the FirstNames property.

Comment: @Bells I tried using NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RoomSlots[i].Guest); but it doesn't resolve the issue. Actually if you see, I am firing the NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RoomSlots); so, it should bind the whole list again. I just did this for testing (I am not updating the whole List<RoomSlot>, but just the Guest record). But I think you are correct. I should fire NotifyPropertyChanged for Guest instead of Guest.FirstNames.

Comment: Sometimes (for bools for instance) I have to put mode=twoway (but it does not have any sense). Might be in this case it needs too.

Comment: @JuanPabloGarciaCoello, Just to be sure, I tried your suggestion but it does not work too.

Comment: And the first time it binds a value?

Comment: @JuanPabloGarciaCoello, Yes, if when I set Guest.FirstNames initially when I receive RoomSlots collection, it does appear in view. Please see my EDIT to see the code that initializes ObservableCollection<RoomSlots> property

Comment: I do not think it has to be about the Caliburn NotificationProperty, have you tried notify NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RoomSlots[i].Guest);

Comment: And can you try to create a textblock without observables change the FirstNames and watch what happens

Comment: @JuanPabloGarciaCoello, If I set the **Guest.FirstNames** instead of **Guest**, that is `slot.Guest.FirstNames = changedRecord.Record.FirstNames`, it works. They why not `slot.Guest = changedRecord.Record` ? Really strange !

Comment: @JuanPabloGarciaCoello, Thanks for the help. I have got it working although I don't understand it clearly. Please see **EDIT 2**

Comment: I do not know, I always use my custom implementation of INotifyPropertychange that I always understand. Glad to help